# K Nearest Neighbor classifier

Tags: opencv, knn

I have set of about 200 points (x,y) of an image. The 200 data belong to 11 classes (which I think will become the class labels). My problem is how do I represent the x, y values as one data?

My first thought is that I should represent them separately with the labels and then when I get a point to classify, I will classify x and y separately. Something in me tells me that this is incorrect.

Please advice me how to present the x,y value as one data element.

Comment: Explain better what the points are and which the labels. Give examples.

Comment: Points are (x,y) coordinates planes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine what problem you meet. In kNN algorithm, we can use variables with multiple dimensions, you just need to use `list` in python standard library or `array` in Numpy library to organize the data such as :  `group = numpy.array([[1.0,1.1],[1.0,1.0],[0,0],[0,0.1]])`
or `group = [[1.0,1.1],[1.0,1.0],[0,0],[0,0.1]]` to represent (1.0,1.1) (1.0,1.0) (0,0) (0,0.1).
However, I suggest to use numpy, as there're so many functions in it and they are implemented by C language which ensure the efficiency of programs.
If you use numpy, you'd better to do all the operations in matrix way, for example, you can use `point=tile([0,0],(3,1))`and`distance(group-point)`(distance is a function written by me) to calculate the distance without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The key is not representation but distance calculation instead. The points in your case are essentially **one element** but with two **dimensions** `(x, y)`. The kNN algorithm can handle n-dimension case itself: it finds the k-nearest neighbors. So you can use the euclidean distance `d((x1, y1), (x2, y2))=((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)^0.5`, where `(x1, y1)` represents the first point to calculate, as the distances of points in your case.